# Calcuating Momentum

Tags: momentum

> A 50-kilogram object is moving at a speed of 10 meters per second.

I will begin to learn the momentum next week but  I want to learn it before my classmates to be better.

**Here is my question:**

Will i use this formula to calcuate its momentum?

> **p** = m**v**

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What about simply reading your textbook in advance? Or checking [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum)? At any rate, the answer is **yes**, your equation is correct, but please check the page [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), whose first advice is **thoroughly search for an answer *before* asking your question**.

Comment: Also is it allowed to ask formula here? thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: yes.

Momentum (p) = mass $\times$ velocity, which can be written using the shorthand $$p=mv$$ and as $v$ and therefore $p$ are vectors, these are bolded: $$\mathbf{p} = m\mathbf{v}$$

An important thing about momentum often involved in problem solving is the law of conservation of momentum - the momentum going into a particular situation and coming out of a particular situation must always be the same.

Let's take a look at a simple problem like yours:

> Find the momentum of an 8 kg bowling ball rolling at 2 m/s.

$\mathbf{p} = 8\text{ kg}\times 2\text{ m/s} = 16 \text{ kg m/s}$

Another, more interesting problem is

> A 5 kg fish swimming 1 m/s swallows an absent minded 1 kg fish swimming toward it at a velocity that brings both fish to a halt immediately after lunch. What is the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ of the smaller fish before lunch?

First, let's choose our directions - positive will be to the right, negative to the left, and we'll assume the smaller fish was swimming left and the larger fish right.

Now, we use the law of conservation of momentum, so since the momentum was zero at the end (both fish were at a halt) the starting total momentum must have been zero, or $5\text{ kg}\times 1\text{ m/s} + 1\text{ kg}\times v = 0$. From here we just solve, to get $v\text{ m/s}\times 1\text{ kg} = -5\text{ kg m/s}$ which gets you $v \text{ m/s} = -5\text{ m/s}$, so the velocity of the smaller fish was $-5 \text{ m/s}$.

Hopefully this all helps you solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

The object is already moving at a constant velocity. This means that it has already undergone acceleration which has been ended. So everything there is to know about the application of momentum has already been involved and has ended before we were invited to make our observation. We have only one assignment which does not involve explaining what momentum is. All that we can do, with the information supplied is to calculate the sum total of momentum acquired by unknown means.

When a problem in momentum has occurred and change is no longer involved, then one is solving for the solution for where we are? For example, the solution of the application of momentum is a simple calculation involving mass and velocity. This equation does not tell us what momentum is. It tells us what the application of momentum has achieved. Lets back up and explain what must have happened in the past?